# New chef node not showing up in the chef-manage console in chef-server

Tags: chef-infra

I have a new Chef environment running the following:
Server running chef-server 12.9.1 and chef-manage
Clients running chef-12.15.19

I have set the server up and it has all been working with nodeserver1. If I run the client and node commands I see it correctly...

```
[chefuser@chefserver chef-repo]$ knife node list
chefnode1
[chefuser@chefserver chef-repo]$ knife client list
chefnode1
organisation-validator
```

The 'chefnode1' node is also visible under 'nodes' in the chef-manage console.

Now if I bootstrap a new node - 'chefnode2', it too is visible using the above commands:

```
[chefuser@chefserver chef-repo]$ knife client list
chefnode1
chefnode2
organisation-validator
[chefuser@chefserver chef-repo]$ knife node list
chefnode1
chefnode2
```

However, this is NOT visible in the chef-manage console after refreshing the page. It's my understanding that it should be.

If I go to the node-URL in the console:
    https://chefserver/organizations/organisation/nodes/chefnode1

and then replace 'chefnode1' with 'chefnode2', you will see the page for 'chefnode2'. When you go back to the 'nodes' page, it is still not visible in the list.

This is repeatable on my environment. Is there something I should be doing differently?

**Edit:**
I have since deleted and re-added chefnode1 and it too is no longer visible in the nodes list. I can still see both nodes if I access their URLs directly.

I did notice in th elogs that when I go to the nodes list, it does a solr search. Could it be that solr is not updating when the nodes are added?

Comment: Did it appear after refreshing the node page on chef-manage console?

Comment: Maybe check the chef-server log with `chef-server-ctl tail` while going to the nodes page.

Comment: Mrigesh, I forgot to mention that. No it did not. That's why I went on to try all the local browser cache clearing methods.

Comment: Tensibal, I did not. I will do so. I did not know about that command.

Comment: So i'm not seeing any errors in the logs.

However, I did notice that I was wrong in the question. I don't see the nodes in the list, even after I access the URL directly as mentioned above.

Comment: I also noticed in the logs that solr is used when showing the nodes. Could it be that Solr is not updating when the node is added?